# skip to content - focus on link

Tags: jquery, html, accessibility

i want to add skip to content link at my site and the focus will be on a link.

but when i focus on that link (after clicking on 'skip to content') the link get focus but i can't click on enter to actually trigger the link.

```
<div class="skiptocontent"><a id="skiptocontent" href="#main" class="">skip to main content</a></div>

<a tabindex="-1" name="maincontent" id="main" class="" href="" alt="movie"><h1 id="movie_name">name</h1></a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#skiptocontent').click(function() {
        $("#"+$(this).attr("href").slice(1)+"")
        .focus()
        .effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
    });
});
```

and then, if i click on tab again, i'm going back to 'skip to content link'

Answer (score 1):

Remove `tabindex="-1"` which means "not focusable"

Comment: not working. i press on tab, enter and then i try to press on enter again.

Comment: You have no href value in the link which is wrapped around the H1. It can't go anywhere unless you give it a destination.

Comment: `tabindex="-1"` does not mean "not focusable" it means not _naturally_ focusable, but it is _programmatically_ focusable

Comment: @harris It depends on the browser you are using. In some outdated browsers, giving focus to an element with `tabindex=-1` would give visual focus but not keyboard focus. In any case, an anchor with a `href` attribute should not have the `tabindex` set to -1 which would mean that a link accessible to mouse users would be not accessible to keyboard users.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Adam regarding tabindex='-1'.  You are breaking the second rule of ARIA use, "Do not change native semantics, unless you really have to."

https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#second-rule-of-aria-use

By setting tabindex to -1, you are essentially changing the semantic nature of the anchor tag.  It can no longer can receive focus using the TAB key.  A screen reader user won't find it by tabbing.  They'd have to bring up a list of links or navigate with the virtual cursor.

Laying that aside for the minute, I can replicate the problem in Firefox but it works fine in Chrome and IE.

```
<a href='#'>one</a><br>
<a href='#' id='foo' onclick='alert("foo")'>two</a><br>
<a href='#'>three</a><br>
<a href='#'>four</a><br>
<a href='#foo' onclick='document.getElementById("foo").focus()'>five</a><br>
```

I can TAB to link five, hit ENTER, and the focus moves to link two.  In Chrome and IE, the focus indicator outline is drawn around link two and when I hit ENTER, the alert box is displayed.

In Firefox, the focus is NOT drawn but the focus sort of moves link two.  Hitting ENTER does NOT display the alert box.  If I tab or shift-tab off link two, it moves to three or one, respectively.

Interestingly enough, if I run with JAWS or NVDA, it *does* work in Firefox.

Comment: It will work with `onclick='document.getElementById("foo").focus();return false;'`.